# CVS Plugin for Atom

Tags: atom-editor

Is there any CVS plugin for Atom? I've searched for one through the application, on google, etc. and it just seems to have no support for versioning with CVS. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Really? Like nobody here knows about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't get any responses for this over here, I posted the same question on Atom's own forum and it seems like there are no CVS-supporting packages. One possible way is to use a terminal package to run CVS commands as described here.

https://discuss.atom.io/t/cvs-plugin-for-atom/49919

Posting this just so that in case someone else has the same question, at least they know this 1 alternative to a CVS plugin.